# Django, can't make options selected

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make the options in my select `selected`. In my code each user is giving scores to each other. I've tryed a few things but it doesn't work. The option should remain selected if the selected value is equal to the grade given to the user. I've used `AbstractUser` that's why there is `User = get_user_model()`, but I decided not to show it since it was useless.

**models.py**

```
class Score(models.Model):
    VALUE = (
        (1, "Score 1"),
        (2, "Score 2"),
        (3, "Score 3"),
        (4, "Score 4"),
        (5, "Score 5"),
        (6, "Score 6"),
        (7, "Score 7"),
        (8, "Score 8"),
        (9, "Score 9"),
        (10, "Score 10"),
    )
    granted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0)
    granted_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0, related_name='granted_to')
    grade = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=VALUE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.granted_to)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def vote(request):
    User = get_user_model()
    data = dict()
    data['users'] = User.objects.exclude(username=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "rating" in request.POST:
            for key in request.POST:
                if 'grade_' in key:
                    awarded_grade = Score.objects.filter(granted_by=request.user,
                                                       granted_to__id=key.split('_')[1]).first()
                    if awarded_grade:
                        awarded_grade.grade = request.POST.get(key)
                        awarded_grade.save()
                    else:
                        Score.objects.create(granted_by=request.user,
                                               granted_to_id=key.split('_')[1],
                                               grade=request.POST.get(key))
    data['values'] = Score.VALUE
    data['grade'] = Score.objects.filter(granted_by=request.user)
    return render(request, 'vote.html', data)
```

**vote.html**

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.date_joined|date:"d.m.Y H:i" }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.username }} </td>
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>
            <select title="selecting_grade" name="grade_{{ user.id }}">
                {% for value in values %}
                    <option value="{{ value.0 }}" {% for a in grades %} {% if a.grade == value.0 %}selected{% endif %} {% endfor %} >{{ value.0 }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tryed something like this in the console:

```
user_grade = Score.objects.filter(granted_by__username='Stalone', granted_to__username='Fane')
user_grade
<QuerySet [<Score: Fane>]>

for x in granted_user:
    print(x.grade)

2
```

or:

```
a = CustomUser.objects.all()
for user in a:
    grades = user.granted_to.values()
    print(grades)
<QuerySet [{'id': 22, 'grade': 5, 'granted_to_id': 14, 'granted_by_id': 1}]>
<QuerySet [{'id': 21, 'grade': 5, 'granted_to_id': 15, 'granted_by_id': 1}]>
<QuerySet [{'id': 19, 'grade': 5, 'granted_to_id': 16, 'granted_by_id': 1}]>
<QuerySet [{'id': 23, 'grade': 7, 'granted_to_id': 17, 'granted_by_id': 1}]>
<QuerySet [{'id': 20, 'grade': 8, 'granted_to_id': 18, 'granted_by_id': 1}]>
<QuerySet [{'id': 24, 'grade': 7, 'granted_to_id': 19, 'granted_by_id': 1}]>
```

To see if I can get the score given to each user and use them in selected, I got them, but I didn't manage to work with them, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views.py you are passing `grade`

```
data['grade'] = Score.objects.filter(granted_by=request.user)
```

But in vote.html, you are iterating with `grades`

```
<option value="{{ value.0 }}" {% for a in grades %} {% if a.grade == value.0 %}selected{% endif %} {% endfor %} >{{ value.0 }}</option>
```

Either change `grade` as `grades` in `views.py` or change `grades` as `grade` in `vote.html`

Comment: ok that's one thing, but now for all the users appears grade 3 as selected, even tought i gave it only to one user, see here http://imgur.com/a/LYyoQ, up you can see the grade id - grade | grade id - grade

Comment: You have to replace the if condition `{% if a.grade == value.0 %}` with  this `{% if user.id == a.granted_to.id and a.grade == value.0 %}`

Comment: Great! If it solved your problem mark this as right answer :)

Comment: np, i'm actually shocked i missed only that, i've been working at it for 3 days